# Stripe connect service, How save the return id

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate "Stripe connect" into my webbapp (Reactjs), I'm currently working on the creation of the seller account, after the seller provide all the info in the pre-build form provided from stripes, stripes make a GET request to my webserver according to stripe docs

[image: From stripe docs]

Then I made a GET handler in my webserver that waits for the request, and then request to Stripe the id of the account created...

[image]

But now I have to save the stripe_user_id in my database, but I dont know how to identify which user made the request... do you have any idea?? Because I have the id of stripe account but not the uid that identify the user in my db.

Comment: you can add a `&state` parameter to the authorise URL that will be set on the Stripe redirect and read that to identify the user(https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-request). Or just authenticate as you would normally, for example cookies, those would still be set on the redirect.

Comment: mmh do you think will be a good idea to put in state the uid of the user saved in my db??